# Elastux: Apache 500 eror after fresh install

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

After installing the Elastix 4.0 distro, I always have a broken web-admin panel. What am I doing wrong?

**/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log**

```
[Fri Oct 07 22:34:08.636204 2016] [:error] [pid 4510] [client 192.168.88.88:50414] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: unable to write file /var/www/html/var/templates_c/wrt57f7eaa09b4319_91812285 <-- \n  thrown in /usr/share/php/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 46
```

Comment: `unable to write file` seems obvious enough. fix the permissions on that file/directories.

Comment: @M They're all right: 775.

Comment: doesn't mean much. if the folder's owned by `foo:bar`, and the webserver's running as `baz`, then it's getting a `5` and can't write.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the `/var/www/html/var/templates_c` directory writable by the user the web server is running under. For example:

```
chmod -R +w /var/www/html/var/templates_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache should work under asterisk user.

/var/www/html/ and /var/lib/php should be changed to same owner.